# Wrong return type from json_serializable?

Tags: json, flutter

I have a Dio service that is returning some json:

```
final response = await di<Api>().dio.get('Measurement');
final List<InspectionResponse> ret = response.data.map((e) => InspectionResponse.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

My json look like this:

```
[
  {
    id: a7fa071d-d518-4c65-8dd1-4c0a04939f45,
    blobName: d19e5f92-f326-437f-8e72-72268def65ec_42a4c288-ee16-4332-91eb-d961201c086d,
    description: null,
    measurementType: 1,
    state: 3,
    score: 0.32693514227867126,
    tagName: Grit-Fine,
    createdAt: 2022-09-02T12: 43: 48.582Z
  },
  {
    id: a7fa071d-d518-4c65-8dd1-4c0a04939f46,
    blobName: d19e5f92-f326-437f-8e72-72268def65ec_42a4c288-ee16-4332-91eb-d961201c086d,
    description: null,
    measurementType: 1,
    state: 3,
    score: 0.32693514227867126,
    tagName: Grit-Fine,
    createdAt: 2022-09-02T12: 43: 48.582Z
  }
]
```

My model is this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class InspectionResponse {
  final String id;
  final String blobName;
  final int state;
  final int measurementType;
  final double score;
  final String tagName;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final String? description;

  InspectionResponse(this.id, this.blobName, this.state, this.measurementType,
      this.score, this.tagName, this.createdAt, this.description);

  factory InspectionResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$InspectionResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$InspectionResponseToJson(this);
}
```

And the genetated _$InspectionResponseFromJson:

```
InspectionResponse _$InspectionResponseFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    InspectionResponse(
      json['id'] as String,
      json['blobName'] as String,
      json['state'] as int,
      json['measurementType'] as int,
      (json['score'] as num).toDouble(),
      json['tagName'] as String,
      DateTime.parse(json['createdAt'] as String),
      json['description'] as String?,
    );
```

The line:

```
final List<InspectionResponse> ret = response.data.map((e) => InspectionResponse.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Give me this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<InspectionResponse>'
```

But I do not understand this? The .map function convert the List<dynamic> to List<InspectionResponse> I would think, as the InspectionResponse.fromJson(e) returns a InspectionResponse, right? So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
final List<InspectionResponse> ret = response.data.map<InspectionResponse>((e) => InspectionResponse.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: And it does, oh man so I just needed to tell it what type to expect. Thank you

Comment: final List ret = response.data.map((e) => InspectionResponse.fromJson(e)).toList(); should also work btw, but i think the first solution is better :D